# Make Jquery text a clickable link

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make blahblah@gmail.com a clickable link?

I'd like to include

```
href="mailto:xxxx@gmail.com"
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u8xqrp96/)**

```
$('#hello').attr('data-originalText', function() {
    return (this.textContent || this.innerText).trim();
}).hover(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(this).text('blahblah@gmail.com').fadeIn();
        });
    },

    function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(800, function() {
            $(this).text($(this).attr('data-originalText')).fadeIn();
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: You'll have to use `a` elements for links then.

Answer (score 1):

Convert this

```
$(this).text('blahblah@gmail.com').fadeIn();
```

to this

```
$(this).html('<a href="mailto:xxxx@gmail.com">blahblah@gmail.com</a>').fadeIn();
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/ebnc22bj/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .html() in order to get html to display.

Replace: `$(this).text('blahblah@gmail.com').fadeIn();`

With: `$(this).html('<a href="mailto:blahblah@gmail.com">blahblah@gmail.com</a>').fadeIn();`

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u8xqrp96/1/